# Sourcing motors by physical dimensions

Tags: motor

I have a 1inch square tube that I would like to place a motor into. [image: small gear motor inside steel square tube]

The motor I have takes up approximately 1/2 of the available space (roughly 3/4 inch I.D.) I would like to find the largest motor that will fit in the space without having to cobble too much of a housing.

Where/how can i find motors by physical dimensions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Typically form follows function - you specify a torque requirement and the physical size is a result. There's no chance a motor that will fit into that hole is going to move something on the same scale as the tube steel.

Comment: I'm trying to fit the largest motor i can in that tube. Design decisions have been made. Thank you.

Comment: Motor sizing and selection is part of the design decision process! As suggested by Chuck, just start searching for motors at different suppliers' websites ([Robotshop](http://www.robotshop.com) is another good one). The actual overall size of the motor is not necessarily going to reflect the performance, so you need to specify your requirements better. Do you just want any motor at all no matter how weak but want it big enough that you need less "stuff" to mount it inside the tube?

Comment: The primary concern is fitting the motor inside the tube. Torque is of secondary importance, and speed is of fairly low importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/motors-solenoids-driver-boards-modules/motors-ac-dc/983125) has the ability to sort by physical size (body diameter). I would have thought other sites would offer this as well, but Mouser and Tower Hobbies don't appear to.